# Expected identifier for every occurance of "(Class)class" in LARSAdController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, import

I'm currently trying to add [LARSAdController](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController) to my iOS project with no success.
As soon as i import the files via `#import "LARSAdController.h"` in my AppDelegate.h the build process fails and on every occurance of `(Class)class` in LARSAdController.h i get the cryptic error "Expected identifier". BTW I'm using cocoapods.

Example:

```
- (void)registerAdClass:(Class)class;
```

which seems fine to me...

If i create a blank project and import the files they compile, so the problem must be in some relation to my code. Anyone got an idea what may cause this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: as the (Class)class part is located in the external lib i don't want to modify them. and i guess the external files aren't the issue as they get importet into the blank project correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in C++, so I would imagine that some of your project uses Objective-C++.

To solve this, use `#import LARSAdController.h` in Objective-C **implementation files** only, and remove its use from header files. You can use `@class` to forward-declare any occurrences of whatever classes are defined in `LARSAdController.h` in header files (this is best-practise anyway).

If you need to use `LARSAdController` from an Objective-C++ class then this is more complicated and you will need to use an Objective-C proxy object or modify their header files (which isn't ideal).

Comment: ok my compiler settings were set to objc++ fix and not "according to file type". this raises some new errors in different files. i'll come back if the forward declaration worked or was needed anyway.

Comment: ok as i understand the main problem is the rather suboptimal choice of the "class" parameter name, which makes it unable to use in objc++ files, right?